# Issue: try connect with a Socket.io Server without port using a client application

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, socket.io, client-applications

everyone!

I'm in an issue.
I'm trying to connect in a server with my client application.
My server is hosting by Modulus that have no port to access URL.
When I try to call `io('my-application.onmodulus.net')`, the browser (chrome) returns me a failed GET `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` with a PORT setted in GET URL.

I tested the URL without the PORT in the browse and works.
There's a way to GET socket.io connect from then client without socket.io set a PORT in URL?

Here's my code:

I try of different ways to call this method, and I don't find OPTIONS parameter documentation.

```
var socket = io('my-application.onmodulus.net', {multiplex: false, path: '/socket.io'});
```

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

In socket.io, if you pass anything as the first argument to `io()` to specify the hostname, then it should be in URL form, not just a hostname.

If you don't pass anything (e.g. you just call `io()`), then socket.io will connect to the same host and port as the current web page.

So, you could use:

```
var socket = io('http://my-application.onmodulus.net/socket.io', {multiplex: false});
```

or, if you're connecting to the same host and port as your web page, you could just leave out the URL and use:

```
var socket = io({multiplex: false});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.
I just fix that.

I pass URL:80 and works.